# Python: Max recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, object, recursion, methods, import

I have looked at the other answers to this question from this website, but Im still stuck.
After adding, setrecursion limit and stack_size, my screen just shows the starting board. I followed "Tech with Tim" step by step but I'm not fully getting the answer. Now, I did notice that he was using PyCharm and I'm using VSCode, if that makes a difference let me know, but besides that or the size of the recursion, I do not know what's wrong. What do I need to change to get the solved puzzle printed?

Code:
(Edited: Revision from @yut23)

```
board = [
    [7, 8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
    [6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 0, 9],
    [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 7, 8],
    [0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 2, 6, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 9, 3, 0],
    [9, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5],
    [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
    [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0],
    [0, 4, 9, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 7]
]

def solve(board):

    find = find_empty(board)

    if not find:
        return True
    else:
        (y, x) = find

    for x in range(1, 10):
        if valid(board, y, x):
            board[y][x] = x

            if solve(board):
                return True
            else:
                board[y][x] = 0

    return False

def valid(board, y, x):

    #Check Row
    for x in range(len(board[0])):
        if (board[y][x] == x) and (y != x):
            return False

    #Check Column
    for x in range(len(board)):
        if (board[x][y] == x) and (y != x):
            return False

    #Check Box
    box_x = x // 3
    box_y = y // 3

    for x in range(box_y * 3, box_y * 3 + 3):
        for y in range(box_x * 3, box_x *3 + 3):
            if board[x][y] == x and (x,y) != y:
                return False
    return True

def print_board(board):

    for x in range(len(board)):
        if (x % 3 == 0) and (x != 0):
            print("- - - - - - - - - - - - ")

        for y in range(len(board[0])):
            if (y % 3 == 0) and (y != 0):
                print(" | ", end = "")                   
            if y == 8:
                print(board[x][y])
            else:
                print(str(board[x][y]) + " ", end = "")

def find_empty(board):

    for x in range(len(board)):
        for y in range(len(board[0])):
            if board[y][x] == 0:
                return (y, x) #row, column
    return None

print_board(board)
solve(board)
print("__________________")
print_board(board)
```

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: From `solve(board)` you are calling `solve(board)` again. How do you expect this is going to stop?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm not sure. This is exactly how "Teach With Tim" has it set up and it works fine. Again, hes using PyCharm and I'm using VSCode, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @MichaelM. Nothing comes back when I used a try block just now. Only thing that prints is the original board. I'm not getting the "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error anymore because of the imports but I don't know how to return the solved puzzle.

Comment: Using a different IDE won't change anything about this. I'm certain there is a difference between your code and "Teach With Tim"'s code that you are overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

Your position index variables `x` and `y` are mixed up in `find_empty()`: you check `board[x][y] == 0`, but it should be `board[y][x] == 0` to be consistent with `board[row][col]` in `solve()`. I'd recommend using the same names for your position variables everywhere to avoid these kinds of mistakes.

As a side note, changing the recursion limit is unnecessary for a brute-force sudoku solver, as it should only recurse 81 times at most (once for each unknown in the input). Increasing the stack size is also unnecessary, because you modify the board in-place and so you only ever have to store 81 numbers.

Comment: thank you for the response but now I'm confusing where the x and y should go for the "position" parameter. Currently I am getting: 
TypeError: valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Comment: After looking it over again, I added the x paramater to Valid() and took away all the indexes attached to variables x and y because I was getting this error instead: 
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable. I added the edited code above and now, I'm getting two tables back, which is good because we called it twice, but the second one is still unsolved. Not sure what to fix in the Solve() function to get the answer.

Comment: @ColbyCanselo Your original code works if you replace `return (y, x)` with `return (x, y)` in `find_empty()`.